# reading in file python says its a string

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to read in a file in Python. I have:

```
file_object = open("CourseEnrollment.txt", "r")
print file.read("CourseEnrollment.txt", 5)
```

I know I have the text file in the right place, but when I try this it says it's receiving a string instead of a file. How do I change this?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Because calling `read` on a file object returns a string of your file contents.

Comment: maybe you want print(file_object[5])? Although as @idjaw suggests, some more information on what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: Recommended: `with open("CourseEnrollment.txt") as file_object:`, then you can `file_object.read()`

Comment: Please post the exact error text. Was it `"TypeError: descriptor 'read' requires a 'file' object but received a 'str'"`?